# Galilean Relativity: Clarification

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I am working on a problem that states:

> "A swimmer capable of swimming at a speed $c$ in still water is swimming in a stream in which the current is $u$ (which we assume to be less than $c$). Suppose the swimmer swims upstream a distance $L$ and then returns downstream to the starting point. Find the time necessary to make the round trip, and compare it with the time to swim across the stream a distance $L$ and return "

I was able to get to the point where I got the value of the velocity of the swimmer relative to the stream to be $v =  -c$ 
Hence relative to the observer, the velocity of the swimmer would be
$v = -c + u $

In the solutions manual they state

> "As expected, the velocity relative to the ground has magnitude smaller than $c$ ; it is also negative, since the swimmer is swimming in the negative $x$ direction, so $|v| = c − u$.) "

I understand why the magnitude of $v$ would be $c -  u$, but does this mean everytime I see $u - c = v$, I should change it to $c - u$ because mathematically, $|v| =  \sqrt{(u-c)^2} = c - u$?

Comment: What do you mean by classical relativity? And does c have anything to do with the speed of light? If not, and not relativistic speeds just add and subtract velocities. If yes, the whole thing is nonsense because for a speed c of light, it would not interact with the water at all, and it would always be c. Which it is not in water.

Comment: Just with relation to your last line. $\sqrt{(u-c)^2}=u-c$

Comment: @BobBee I also wondered that for a second. We tend to think of relativity as only post-Einstein, but we usually forget there was (and is) a Galileean relativity for classical mechanics.

Comment: @BobBee Classical relativity is Galilean relativity. It's clear from the context of the title and the idea of problem that c is *not* the speed of light.

Comment: @Continuum Always establish a coordinate system with positive and negative directions when you're working kinematics and dynamics problems. Use vectors with directions described consistent with the coordinates. That saves a LOT of headaches.

Comment: @Bill N I made it clear the if c is not the speed of light and speeds are not relativistic, then just subtract (or add reading between the lines). That covers Galilean relativity, which is the accurate name. And if not it doesn't make sense. So I covered your Galilean case. Classical can be a confusing term, eg, general relatIvity as opposed to quantum gravity. My entry was perfectly clear. When speeds are not relativistic you can use Galilean transformations. High school physics

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what's being asked of you. Whenever you are asked for the speed, you should provide $|v|$. If asked for the velocity, you should provide $v$.

When solving the problem, you should always use $ v$ and not $|v|$. Velocity is a vector quantity and sign MATTERS. The excerpt is saying that when the velocity is negative the object is moving with a speed $|v|$ in the negative $x$ direction.

Whether or not $|v| = c-u$ or $|v| = u-c$ depends on whether $u < c\space $ or $\space c < u$.

In this instance $u< c$ but that will not always be the case.